# MVC5 javascripts breaks in IE11 after azure deployment

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-11

I have an MVC5 webapplication developed in VS2013 & running fine locally on IE11 (Debug & Release and connected to azure sql db), but it fails after deployment to azure websites on three ( so far ) javascript related issues as far as I can see (I´m a MVC newbie).

- Clientside validation no longer works
- JsonResult from Controller is not read by js, but downloads
- jquery.simplecolorpicker.js stopped working (as bootstrap modal)

Works in Chrome

Updated all nuget packages

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Check in the console if these JS are missing, or any error that could be there

Comment: no errors..  All scripts are defined in BundleConfig.. added another fail to question

Comment: IE can be aggressive on its caching which can cause some issues, i tend to hit ctrl-f5 until my fingers bleed whenever a site doesnt work right in it

Comment: ctrl-f5 no go.. It´s the same on different computers (& still OK in Chrome)